# Determining upper bound in terms of big O

Tags: performance, algorithm, optimization, big-o, complexity-theory

How should I go about determining the upper bound of the complexity of these code snippets in terms of big O? I'm just learning about these concepts and am looking for : clues, straight-out responses, best resources on learning more.

I found this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it), but i'm still having trouble adapting the answer.

I'm given these examples:

```
For J = 1 to 10000000000000
    C[J] = A[J] + B[J]



For J = 1 to N
    C[J] = A[J] * B[J]



For J = 1 to N
    For K = 1 to N
        C[J][K] = A[J] * B[K]


For I = 1 to N
    For J = 1 to 10000000000000
        For K = 1 to N
            C[I][J] = A[J][K] * B[K][I]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big O says what is the relationship between the input size and the time/space complexity.

Now onto your examples:

- `For J = 1 to 10000000000000` - The `10000000000000` is just a constant. Even though it is a big number, it doesn't depend on the input size (N), which is why this is O(1)
- `For J = 1 to N` - The number of iterations now directly depends on `N`, this is said to be linear complexity, since if you increase `N` by one, the loop will run one more time.
- Two nested loops - since they both depend on `N`, the complexity is `O(N * N)`

The last one is easy to figure out knowing the above.

Comment: Just checking for comprehension: For the last one, considering that the 10000000000000 is constant, even if there are three for loops it would still just be O(N*N)? Also, why do we multiply the Ns?

Comment: @user25976 Yes it would be just O(N*N), or O(N^2) ... as in N squared.

Comment: @user25976 We multiply the Ns because the inner loop executes N times for each iteration of the outer loop. The outer loop executes N times as well, which gives us N*N.

Comment: Would it still be multiplied if the second two loops are on the same level?

Comment: No, in that case it would equal to 2*O(N), which is asymptotically still O(N).